# jquery $(elem) + specific class identifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is this possible in jQuery?

```
$(elem).('.class').html("new data");
```

I need to change the HTML of a class on the current element because there are multiple elements that have this class. I only want to change the HTML of the class on that specific element. I tried using `.parent()` children closest but to no avail.

The function is called by a select tag that is inside a td which is inside a tr and the data I want to change is in the next tr so it would be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>the td's which htmls i want to change</tr>
```

Also note that `<tr>` holding the select can be added multiple times so there will be more than 1 select thus the `$(elem)` part. also the tr holding the td's will also be added whenever a new tr holding the select is added so here is a sample html code:

Generated HTML code:

```
  <tr class="action-row">
 <td valign="top">CRM Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top"><select name="crm_action[]">
 <option value="add">Add to Group</option>
 <option value="transfer">Transfer to Group</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="funnel_type[]" class="funnel-type" onchange="type_switch(this)">
 options to determine what to display in this tr onchange
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <img src="somewhere/action_delete.png" title="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)"     style="cursor: pointer;"></td>
 </tr>
 //this part should have been inside the above tr as you can see it the php code above
 <tr class="actionrow odd">
 <td class="type-label" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-selection" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
 //end              
 <tr class="action-row">
 <td valign="top">CRM Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="crm_action[]"><option value="add">Add to Group</option>
 <option value="transfer">Transfer to Group</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="funnel_type[]" class="funnel-type" onchange="type_switch(this)">
 another options
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <img src="somewhere/action_delete.png" title="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)"      style="cursor: pointer;">
 </td>
      </tr>
 <tr class="actionrow odd">
 <td class="type-label" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-selection" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: If there are multiple elements of a class, you can find them as @gdoron has suggested and refer to each element like an array element.

Comment: You want to reach second tr from your select ? if i am right... every one is just answering to your title.

Comment: @MohammadAdil yes but the select it self is inside another tr that has a diff class than that of the tr that has the td's i want to change

Comment: You want to change text on change of your select ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil no, i want to change the contents of the td of tr class actionrow but that not all actionrow tr will be changed only the part where the select was changed. i updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `find`?

```
$(elem).find('.class').html("new data");
```

`children` digs one level while `find` digs until it reaches the "leaves".

Comment: define leaves? tried it now but it didn't changed anything until i changed elem to the class that holds the the other classes i wanted to change something like <tr class="test"><td class="1"></td><td class="2"></td></tr> when i changed elem to "test" and find('.1') it did the changes

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether elem is a variable.

```
 $('elem.class').html("new data");
```

or

```
 $(elem).find('.class').html("new data");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting the element

```
$("div") // Can be whatever you want
```

Then adding the class after it like you would in CSS

```
$("div.class")
```

Finally, calling either the `html()` or the `text()` method on the element

```
$("div.class").html("new data")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqRH4/)